# How to get the target achieved date when the target count is derived based on a field in a CROSS APPLY?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sale](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SaleDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerRef] [varchar](20) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Verification](
    [CustomerRef] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [VerificationDate] [date] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (1, CAST(N'2022-02-01' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (2, CAST(N'2022-02-02' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (3, CAST(N'2022-02-03' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (4, CAST(N'2022-02-13' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (5, CAST(N'2022-02-14' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (6, CAST(N'2022-02-15' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (7, CAST(N'2022-02-16' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (8, CAST(N'2022-03-08' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (9, CAST(N'2022-03-08' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (10, CAST(N'2022-03-10' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (11, CAST(N'2022-03-11' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (12, CAST(N'2022-03-12' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (13, CAST(N'2022-03-13' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (14, CAST(N'2022-02-20' AS Date), N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (15, CAST(N'2022-03-14' AS Date), N'1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (16, CAST(N'2022-02-10' AS Date), N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (17, CAST(N'2022-02-11' AS Date), N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (18, CAST(N'2022-02-12' AS Date), N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (19, CAST(N'2022-03-18' AS Date), N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (20, CAST(N'2022-03-19' AS Date), N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (21, CAST(N'2022-03-20' AS Date), N'2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (22, CAST(N'2022-02-15' AS Date), N'3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (23, CAST(N'2022-02-16' AS Date), N'3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (24, CAST(N'2022-02-20' AS Date), N'4')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Sale] ([ID], [SaleDate], [CustomerRef]) VALUES (25, CAST(N'2022-02-21' AS Date), N'4')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Verification] ([CustomerRef], [VerificationDate]) VALUES (N'1', CAST(N'2022-02-01' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Verification] ([CustomerRef], [VerificationDate]) VALUES (N'2', CAST(N'2022-02-10' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Verification] ([CustomerRef], [VerificationDate]) VALUES (N'3', CAST(N'2022-02-15' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Verification] ([CustomerRef], [VerificationDate]) VALUES (N'4', CAST(N'2022-02-20' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Verification] ([CustomerRef], [VerificationDate]) VALUES (N'1', CAST(N'2022-03-10' AS Date))
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Verification] ([CustomerRef], [VerificationDate]) VALUES (N'2', CAST(N'2022-03-20' AS Date))
GO
```

I have written the following query to get the number of sales in the 2-week period from the 1st sale date after the verification date and prior to the next verification date.

```
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT *,LEAD(VERIFICATIONDATE,1,'20990101') OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMERREF ORDER BY VERIFICATIONDATE) AS NEXTVERIFICATIONDATE
FROM VERIFICATION A
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE A
--GET FIRST SALE DATE POST VERIFICATION DATE AND PRIOR TO NEXT VERIFICATION DATE
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT MIN(SaleDate) FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate
     FROM SALE B 
     WHERE A.CUSTOMERREF = B.CUSTOMERREF 
       AND B.SALEDATE >= A.VERIFICATIONDATE
       AND B.SALEDATE < NEXTVERIFICATIONDATE) Z
--GET COUNT OF SALES IN 2 WEEKS FROM THE FIRST SALE DATE POST VERIFICATION DATE (AND PRIOR TO NEXT VERIFICATION DATE)
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) COUNT 
     FROM SALE B 
     WHERE A.CUSTOMERREF = B.CUSTOMERREF
       AND B.SALEDATE >= Z.FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate
       AND SALEDATE < DATEADD(WEEK, 2, Z.FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate)
       AND SALEDATE < NEXTVERIFICATIONDATE) U
```

Against each row, how can I retrieve the sale date value when the count crossed the value of 4?

Expected output is (look at the last column):

```
+-------------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------------+
| CustomerRef | VerificationDate | NEXTVERIFICATIONDATE | FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate | COUNT | TARGETDATE |
+-------------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------------+
|           1 | 2022-02-01       | 2022-03-10           | 2022-02-01                                                     |     5 | 2022-02-13 |
|           1 | 2022-03-10       | 2099-01-01           | 2022-03-10                                                     |     5 | 2022-03-13 |
|           2 | 2022-02-10       | 2022-03-20           | 2022-02-10                                                     |     4 | 2022-02-20 |
|           2 | 2022-03-20       | 2099-01-01           | 2022-03-20                                                     |     1 |            |
|           3 | 2022-02-15       | 2099-01-01           | 2022-02-15                                                     |     2 |            |
|           4 | 2022-02-20       | 2099-01-01           | 2022-02-20                                                     |     2 |            |
+-------------+------------------+----------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+-------+------------+
```

I tried adding another CROSS APPLY as shown below:

```
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT B.SaleDate
     FROM SALE B 
     WHERE A.CUSTOMERREF = B.CUSTOMERREF
       AND B.SALEDATE >= Z.FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate
       AND SALEDATE < DATEADD(WEEK, 2, Z.FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate)
       AND SALEDATE < NEXTVERIFICATIONDATE
       AND ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by b.customerref order by b.saledate)=4) V
```

This gives an error: `Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.`

Based on one of the comments I have written the following which I suppose is the answer:

```
OUTER APPLY(
    SELECT SALEDATE FROM(
    SELECT SALEDATE,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY B.CUSTOMERREF ORDER BY B.SALEDATE) RNO
     FROM SALE B 
     WHERE A.CUSTOMERREF = B.CUSTOMERREF
       AND B.SALEDATE >= Z.FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate
       AND SALEDATE < DATEADD(WEEK, 2, Z.FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate)
       AND SALEDATE < NEXTVERIFICATIONDATE
                   ) TBL
                   WHERE RNO=4
) V
```

Comment: can you share the expected output for improved understanding? @variable

Comment: If you want to filter on the value of windowed aggregate, you need to use a derived table or CTE, and filter on the value when you reference that derived table/CTE.

Comment: @lemon - added expected output to question.

Comment: @Larnu - so I should create a CTE on top and then use it inside the cross apply?

Comment: Or use a derived table, yes.

Comment: @Larnu- The thing is that the value of `FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate` which is needed to calculate the count is only available after the 1st CROSS APPLY.

Comment: You nest derived tables and defined them in subqueries within a `CROSS APPLY`, @variable . `CROSS APPLY (SELECT I FROM (SELECT A FROM (SELECT 1 AS A) AS D) AS Q) AS ca` is valid syntax.

Comment: @Larnu - thanks mate, I have added this to the question (at the bottom) - it works - can you review it to check and maybe also recommend if there is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a running count within the second `APPLY`, then add a conditional aggregation over that count, all within the `APPLY`

```sql
;WITH CTE AS(
SELECT *,LEAD(VERIFICATIONDATE,1,'20990101') OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMERREF ORDER BY VERIFICATIONDATE) AS NEXTVERIFICATIONDATE
FROM VERIFICATION A
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE A
--GET FIRST SALE DATE POST VERIFICATION DATE AND PRIOR TO NEXT VERIFICATION DATE
CROSS APPLY 
    (SELECT MIN(SaleDate) FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate
     FROM SALE B 
     WHERE A.CUSTOMERREF = B.CUSTOMERREF 
       AND B.SALEDATE >= A.VERIFICATIONDATE
       AND B.SALEDATE < NEXTVERIFICATIONDATE) Z
--GET COUNT OF SALES IN 2 WEEKS FROM THE FIRST SALE DATE POST VERIFICATION DATE (AND PRIOR TO NEXT VERIFICATION DATE)
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      COUNT(*) COUNT,
      MIN(CASE WHEN RunningCount = 4 THEN SALEDATE END) DateAt4
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
          COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY B.SALEDATE ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) RunningCount
        FROM SALE B 
        WHERE A.CUSTOMERREF = B.CUSTOMERREF
          AND B.SALEDATE >= Z.FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate
          AND SALEDATE < DATEADD(WEEK, 2, Z.FirstSaleDatePostVerificationDateAndPriorToNextVerifiationDate)
          AND SALEDATE < NEXTVERIFICATIONDATE
    ) U
) U
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7476948378df57eed9003e541c30a0a9)